# Paint App Html5 and Send Email

Tags: html

I've found this great piece of code: http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/#demo-simple

Now, I would like to send the canvas via email in the background. So there should be a „send this canvas“ button and send to my email adress.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible.

using the `toDataURL()` method of the canvas. see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement#Methods) for example... To send it as email you need to send the generated string to a server which sends it to wherever you want.